# Parsing windows 'ipconfig /all' output

Tags: c#, .net, regex, parsing, ipconfig

I am having a bit of trouble parsing the output of 'ipconfig /all' using a regex.
Currently I am using RegexBuddy for testing, but I want to use the regex in C#.NET.

My output is:

```
Ethernet adapter Yes:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : MAC Bridge Miniport
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 02-1F-29-00-85-C9
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::f980:c9c3:a574:37a%24(Preferred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::f980:c9c3:a574:37a7%24(Preferred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::f980:c9c3:a574:37a8%24(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.0.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.0.254
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 520228888
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-17-1C-CC-CF-00-1F-29-00-85-C9
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.162.100.15
                                       192.162.100.16
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

The regex I have written so far is:

```
([ -~]+):.+(?:Description\s)(?:\.|\s)+:\s([ -~]+).+(?:Physical Address)(?:\.|\s)+:\s([ -~]+).+(?:DHCP Enabled)(?:\.|\s)+:\s([ -~]+).+(?:(?:Link-local IPv6 Address)(?:\.|\s)+:\s([ -~]+).+Preferred.+)+
```

The problem is that I want to capture all the useful fields as groups, to get them easily in C#, and for some reason - when I got to capture the multiple 'Link-local IPv6 Address' fields, it stopped working.

I'll appreciate any help,
Thanks.

Edit:
Another problem is that I receive the ipconfig data from a remote machine (there is an unmanaged program there which I don't have control of) - thus I can't use WMI or something like that to get the ipconfig info in another way.

Comment: Why RegEx?  The data already is in a key:value notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why use regex? Your input is in simple key-value format. Use something along the lines of

```
foreach (var line in lines)
{
   var index  = line.IndexOf (':') ;
   if (index <= 0) continue ; // skip empty lines

   var key   = line.Substring (0,  index).TrimEnd (' ', '.') ;
   var value = line.Substring (index + 1).Replace ("(Preferred)", "").Trim () ;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

> but I want to use the regex in C#.NET.

Why Regex? Believe me, you don't want to use regex. A wise man once said:

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 'I know, I'll use regular expressions.' Now they have two problems.

Let me state your 2 problems right now:

- Retrieve information about TCP/IP configuration using ipconfig
- Parse the output from this tool using regex

Actually you could retrieve this information using WMI directly and thus solve your original problem and never think about using regexes again:

```
using (var mc = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration"))
using (var instances = mc.GetInstances())
{
    foreach (ManagementObject instance in instances)
    {
        if (!(bool)instance["ipEnabled"])
        {
            continue;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}", instance["Caption"], instance["ServiceName"], instance["MACAddress"]);

        string[] ipAddresses = (string[])instance["IPAddress"];
        string[] subnets = (string[])instance["IPSubnet"];
        string[] gateways = (string[])instance["DefaultIPGateway"];
        string domains = (string)instance["DNSDomain"];
        string description = (string)instance["Description"];
        bool dhcp = (bool)instance["DHCPEnabled"];
        string[] dnses = (string[])instance["DNSServerSearchOrder"];
    }
}
```

In addition to that you could create strongly typed wrapper for those WMI classes using the [`Mgmtclassgen.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2wkebaxa.aspx) utility making your code even safer and you will be able tpo get rid of the magic strings.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I already know about this way, but my problem is that I receive the ipconfig data from a remote machine (there is an unmanaged program there which I don't have control of)

Answer (score 0):

Surely you can get all this information by using [`NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()`](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getallnetworkinterfaces)